# Uniform convergence of series of function

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series of functions $f_n(x)= x^n/(1+x^n)$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,a]$ where $0<a<1$ and not uniformly on $[0,1)$.

I have come across lots of problems like this , where the open interval make the uniform convergence go , to proof the uniform convergence I used the m test.

Since $f_n(x) \leq x^n=a^n$ which is easy to proof that series $a^n$ is convergent.

What's happen when the open interval comes!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: each $f_n$ is continuous and $f_n(1) = 1/2$.  But if $f_n$ converged uniformly to $0$ on $[0,1)$, there would be $N$ such that ...

Answer (score 0):

To add some detail to Robert's answer:

**In the case of $[0,a]$ for $a<1$:**

Fix $\varepsilon >0$. Then, letting $n \geq \frac{\ln(\varepsilon)}{\ln(a)}$,

$$|f_{n}(x) - 0| = \left |\frac{x^n}{1+x^n} - 0 \right | \leq |x^n| \leq |a^n| < \varepsilon,$$

we have readily shown that $f_{n} \rightrightarrows 0$.

**In the case of $[0,1]$:**

Note that in this case $\ln(a)=0$ and so our choice of $n$ from above is not defined. We also have that $$f_{n}(x) \rightarrow \begin{cases} 0,\, \mathrm{if}\, x \in [0,1) \\ \frac{1}{2},\, \mathrm{if}\, x=1. \end{cases}$$

Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{4}$. Then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, find $x \in [0,1)$ such that $\frac{1}{4} \leq f_{n}(x) < \frac{1}{2}$ (that is, $1 \leq 3x^n < 1$ or $\geq 3^{-1/n} \leq x < 1$) and observe that

$$|f_{n}(x)-0| \geq \frac{1}{4}.$$

This belies a contradiction.